# How to drop an object on a bar button item?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, drag-and-drop

I've got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni2FH.png) collection view, and I want to be able to delete a cell by dragging it in the trash bar button on the right of the bar.

I don't understand how to make the button able to receive a drop,
if it was a UIView I can do

> addInteraction(UIDropInteraction(..))

but since it is a button I can't act this way.

Someone can help me?

Comment: A UIButton inherits from a UIControl which inherits from a UIView, so anything you can do to a UIView you can also do to a UIButton.

Comment: Yeah, but this is a UIBarButtonItem so i can't use addInteraction

Comment: See that now sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a custom view and add interactions to it. And finally, add that to the rightBarButtonItem. Something on the lines of:

```
func viewDidLoadForBarButton() {
        let customView = UIView() //Add your custom UIView() here
        customView.sizeToFit()

        let dropInteraction = UIDropInteraction(delegate: self)
        customView.addInteraction(dropInteraction)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }
```

Let me know if it works.